# Looking for case insensitive MySQL collation where "a" != "ä"

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation, case-insensitive

I'm looking for a MySQL collation for UTF8 which is case insensitive and distinguishes between "a" and "ä" (or more generally, between umlauted / accented characters and their "pure" form). `utf8_general_ci` does the former, `utf8_bin` the latter, bot none does both. If there is no such collation, what can I do to get as close as possible in a `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use `utf8_bin` and in your WHERE clause, force both sides of your comparison to upper or lower case.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine here with `utf8_german2_ci` as collation:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname LIKE "würz%" COLLATE utf8_german2_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked `utf8_bin` like this

```
CREATE TABLE tmp2 (utf8_bin VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin);
INSERT INTO tmp2 VALUES ('nói');

select * from tmp2 where utf8_bin='noi';
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try `utf8_swedish_ci`, it's both case insensitive and distinguishes between *a* and *ä* (but treats e.g. *ü* like *y*).

Collations are language-dependent, and it seems German doesn't have its own [collation in MySQL](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/). (I had a look at your profile, which says you're German.)