# MySQL treats ÅÄÖ as AAO?

Tags: mysql, unicode, encoding, collation

These two querys gives me the exact same result:

```
select * from topics where name='Harligt';
select * from topics where name='Härligt';
```

How is this possible? Seems like mysql translates åäö to aao when it searches. Is there some way to turn this off?

I use utf-8 encoding everywhere as far as i know. The same problem occurs both from terminal and from php.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, this is standard behaviour in the non-language-specific unicode collations.

[9.1.13.1. Unicode Character Sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-unicode-sets.html)

> To further illustrate, the following equalities hold in both utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci (for the effect this has in comparisons or when doing searches, see Section 9.1.7.7, “Examples of the Effect of Collation”):
>
> Ä = A
> Ö = O
> Ü = U

See also [Examples of the effect of collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-collation-effect.html)

You need to  either

- use a collation that doesn't have this "feature" (namely [`utf8_bin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526334/what-effects-does-using-a-binary-collation-have), but that has other consequences)
- use a different collation *for the query only*. This should work:

  ```
   select * from topics where name='Harligt' COLLATE utf8_bin;
  ```

it becomes more difficult if you want to do a case insensitive `LIKE` but **not** have the `Ä = A` umlaut conversion. I know no mySQL collation that is case insensitive and does not do this kind of implicit umlaut conversion. If anybody knows one, I'd be interested to hear about it.

Related:

- [Looking for case insensitive MySQL collation where “a” != “ä”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044268/looking-for-case-insensitive-mysql-collation-where-a-a)
- [MYSQL case sensitive search for utf8_bin field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901066/mysql-case-sensitive-search-for-utf8-bin-field)

Answer (score 5):

Since you are in Sweden I'd recommend using the Swedish collation. Here's an example showing the difference it makes:

```
CREATE TABLE topics (name varchar(100) not null) CHARACTER SET utf8;

INSERT topics (name) VALUES ('Härligt');

select * from topics where name='Harligt';
'Härligt'

select * from topics where name='Härligt';
'Härligt'    

ALTER TABLE topics MODIFY name VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci;

select * from topics where name='Harligt';
<no results>

select * from topics where name='Härligt';
'Härligt'
```

Note that in this example I only changed the one column to Swedish collation, but you should probably do it for your entire database, all tables, all varchar columns.

Comment: This should be working for other languages than swedish so i think utf8_bin is the collation i want, but thanks for letting me know that i can change collation on only one column, that will be really helpful.

Comment: Note that utf8_bin is case sensitive so "härligt" != "Härligt" (applies to unique indexes too).

Answer (score 2):

While collations are one way of solving this, the much more straightforward way seems to me to be the `BINARY` keyword:

```
 SELECT 'a' = 'ä', BINARY 'a' = 'ä'
```

will return `1|0`

In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM topics WHERE BINARY name='Härligt';
```

See also https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_binary.asp

Answer (score 1):

you want to check your collation settings, collation is the property that sets which characters are identical.

these 2 pages should help you

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-general.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see some collation charts. http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/. I'm no sure which is the used utf8_general_ci though.

Here is the chart for utf8_swedish_ci. It shows which characters it interprets as the same. http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_swedish_ci.html