# Collation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, collation

Whether Collate Latin1_General_CS_AS and Collate utf8_bin are same, well they are different the former is for Latin1 charset and the latter is for utf8 charset but i wanted to know whether both of will do case sensitive and Accent sensitive match.

Actually just now i have migrated my database from sql server2000 to MySQL 5.2 and i have a password field which i want to compare with case sensitive and Accent sensitive in sql server that Collate Latin1_General_CS_AS is working fine but i want to know Collate utf8_bin is the replacement for that in MySQL or there are some other better ways to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know SQL server and the collation you mention, but `utf8_bin`, being a [binary collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-collations.html), is indeed case and accent sensitive.

You don't necessarily need to have the entire database in that collation though - binary collations are not great at [sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526334/what-effects-does-using-a-binary-collation-have). You can force a binary comparison in a non-binary collation (like `utf8_general_ci`) using the [`COLLATE` keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html):

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE password COLLATE utf8_bin = "abcäöü";
```