# MySQL making whitespace matter

Tags: mysql

Apparently a very rare issue, but IMO extremely annoying and WRONG: Trailing whitespace in MySQL aren't used in comparison:

```
mysql> SELECT "A" = "A ";
+------------+
| "A" = "A " |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is especially problematic in the following scenario:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eq WHERE name != TRIM(name);
+------------+
| COUNT(*)   |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE eq SET name=TRIM(name);
Query OK, 866 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 650907  Changed: 866  Warnings: 0
```

Is there a way to configure MySQL to treat whitespace properly?

Comment: A binary comparison will prevent removal of trailing spaces:  `SELECT BINARY 'a ' = BINARY 'a';`

Answer (score 6):

According to [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), one quick fix is to use LIKE:

> Per the SQL standard, LIKE performs matching on a per-character basis, thus it can produce results different from the = comparison operator:
>
> ...
>
> In particular, trailing spaces are significant, which is not true for CHAR or VARCHAR comparisons performed with the = operator ...

as long as you don't use any wildcards, this should be identical to `=`. This Stack Overflow question seems to support the assumption: [Equals(=) vs. LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like)

The manual doesn't state whether [`STRCMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp) is stricter than `=` in terms of whitespace, and I can't try it out right now - that might be worth taking a look at, too, as it makes it clearer *why* `=` is not used.

Binary comparison as suggested by tombom is also an option, but will have other side-effects (like the stricter comparison of Umlauts, eg. `A` and `Ä` will be different) which you may or may not want. More info on the effects of using a binary comparison in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526334/what-effects-does-using-a-binary-collation-have)

Comment: `STRCMP` seems to act identical to `=`. While `LIKE` also pays attention to the capitalization. Thanks!

Comment: @Mikhail ahh, so neither works for you? That sucks. Then I guess binary comparison is the only way to go

Answer (score 2):

You may use LIKE

```
SELECT "A" LIKE "A ";
```

will return 0 but

```
SELECT "A" LIKE "A";
```

returns 1

Answer (score 2):

Binary comparison is the magic word.

[Binary Comparison in MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-binary-op.html)

```
mysql> SELECT 'a' = 'A';
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT BINARY 'a' = 'A';
        -> 0
mysql> SELECT 'a' = 'a ';
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT BINARY 'a' = 'a ';
        -> 0
```

Comment: +1, but note that this may change other behaviour as well (like the comparison of Umlauts)