# Comparison of two strings in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written an ajax function to check if a value exists inside the database.

For example consider two strings "Book" and "book". In my current situation "Book" is there inside the Database and if I search using the query below

```
Select * from Cat where name='book'

OR

Select * from Cat where name like 'book'
```

It returns an empty result set since the 'b' is in lowercase. My collation is utf8_bin.
What will be the query to evaluate in such a way that it will be the same whether it is upper case or lower case.

Comment: What's wrong with `name like 'book'`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What effects does using a binary collation have?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526334/what-effects-does-using-a-binary-collation-have)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `upper()` function to make both strings to upper case:

```
Select * from Cat where upper(name)=upper('book')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can use the upper or lower function in the comparison

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIKE` instead `=`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Or also convert everythiing to upper/lower before comparing

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper

Comment: I have told in the question that I tried like also.