# Query uft8mb4 case insensitive in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8, utf8mb4

I am used to doing a case-insensitive match in mysql on `utf8` fields, such as:

```
select * from connections where full_name like '%david%'
```

However, it seems that `utf8mb4` does not support case-insensitive searches. How would I do the same against that in mysql?

The table I have is:

```
CREATE TABLE `connections` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `full_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7160 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: What's the collation of the `name` field?

Comment: @zerkms updated the question with a table definition.

Comment: `utf8mb4_bin` collation is not case insensitive. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5526334/251311

Comment: @zerkms I see -- so basically if a field supports emojis in mysql it cannot do case-insensitive searching? Or is there an alternative approach to get case-insensitive matching with emojis?

Comment: You can change `COLLATE` on runtime


    `SELECT 
     *
    FROM 
     full_name  COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci LIKE '%david%'`

This should pick out `David` or `david` see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7y7kbji7w8o5nKz5P6b83e/1)   i would place this as a answer if the topic wasn't closed.

Comment: @RaymondNijland perfect, this is what I was looking for with the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @David542 they can. Charset and collation are tangential concepts https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-collation.html

Comment: utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci is "Case Insensitive" and (I think) also distinguishes Emoji.  Other `COLLATIONs` may be different.  You must use `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` to handle Emoji.