# MySQL DB selects records with and without umlauts. e.g: '.. where something = FÖÖ'

Tags: mysql, collation, equivalent, diacritics

My Table collation is "utf8_general_ci". If i run a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield = "FÖÖ"
```

i get results where:

```
...  myfield = "FÖÖ"
...  myfield = "FOO"
```

is this the default for "utf8_general_ci"?

What collation should i use to only get records where myfield = "FÖÖ"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL treats ÅÄÖ as AAO?!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607130/mysql-treats-aao-as-aao)

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_field LIKE ('%ö%'  COLLATE utf8_bin)
```

Comment: When providing code that solves the problem, it is best to also give at least a short explanation of how it works so that folks reading won't have to mentally parse it line by line to understand the differences.

Comment: the answer came from mr satan, he does not need to explain.

Comment: ERROR 1253 (42000): COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'

Answer (score 3):

A list of the collations offered by MySQL for Unicode character sets can be found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

If you want to go all-out and require strings to be *absolutely identical* in order to test as equal, you can use `utf8_bin` (the binary collation). Otherwise, you may need to do some experimentation with the different collations on offer.

Answer (score 0):

For scandinavian letters you can use utf8_swedish_ci fir example.

Here is the character grouping for utf8_swedish_ci. It shows which characters are interpreted as the same.
http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_swedish_ci.html

Here's the directory listing for other collations. I'm no sure which is the used utf8_general_ci though. http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/