# match special characters from input to stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, diacritics

I saved some German characters on the database by entity (eg. **föo** => **`f&ouml;o`**).

Now I have a query that search for a match just using `LIKE %search_word%`. The `search_word` will probably be an input containing special German characters. Can you suggest of the most efficient way to compare my `search_word` to the one stored in the database?

Huge thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is a valid answer already: [MySQL DB selects records with and without umlauts. e.g: '.. where something = FÖÖ'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279374/mysql-db-selects-records-with-and-without-umlauts-e-g-where-something-f)

You have to ensure that the string encoding (e.g. UTF8) and your (MySQL) DB charset do match. Look at what collations do and if utf8_bin can help.

Answer (score 0):

use the same entity conversion at `search_word` before putting it in the query.

or you can stop saving the data whit entity conversion, and do the converstion when you need them insted