# Hibernate's like or ilike restrictions and German umlauts

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, utf-8

I noticied that non of hibernate's `ilike` queries works with German umlauts such as ü, ö etc... As far as I understand it is  a MySQL's issue.

I searched for the solutions and it seems there are only two:

1. Replace all the umlautes with the appropriate character sets. For
   example, `ü` with `ue` etc...
2. Semi-solution because I don't know how to implement it with hibernate described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2607164/705869) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11761321/705869)

So the questions are: what is the better way and how to implement #2 with hibernate?

Thank you in advance