# MySQL - Searching for Swedish Characters

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, unicode

I have stored Swedish words in MysQL database. The encoding of the table is

```
utf8_unicode_ci
```

I also tried

```
utf8_swedish_ci
```

when I'm doing a search in database, 'a' and 'ä' are treated the same. So the results include both words that begin with a and ä. This is true vice-versa as well.
My application is developed with CakePHP and I have the following in my core.php

```
Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');
```

Am I missing anything here?

This is my query:

```
$term = $this->request->query['term'];

$this->loadModel('Words');
$condition = array('word LIKE' => trim($term) . '%', 'is_active' => true);
$words = $this->Words->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('word'),
    'limit' => 7,
    'conditions' => $condition));

return $this->respond($words, true);
```

I use to for Jquery autocomplete:

```
$(function () {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: 'autocomplete'
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you show your query?

Comment: I added to the post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607130/mysql-treats-%C3%85%C3%84%C3%96-as-aao

Answer (score 0):

```
$query_result = $this->Words->query("SELECT word FROM tbl_words WHERE word LIKE '" . $term . "%' COLLATE utf8_bin LIMIT 7 ;");
```

This works great for me. Thanks @Mihai for your comment.

Comment: There's nothing better then the smell of fresh SQL injection vulnerabilities in the morning :) Please manually escape your user input (`DboSource::value()`) **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query**  or use prepared statements **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#prepared-statements**

Comment: I'm trying to do this way but for some reason I'm not getting anything: $db = $this->Words->getDataSource();
$query_result = $db->fetchAll(
'SELECT word FROM tbl_words WHERE word LIKE "?%" COLLATE utf8_bin AND is_active = TRUE LIMIT 7', array('als')
            );

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I wanted to list all the autocomplete suggesstions by a tag which may contain swedish characters. I had already a right charset in the mysql database. So no issues there. But I was still failing to search properly from the mysql database with a swedish tag name. However, it turns out to be not related to mysql. I missed to decode the tag in my php backend.

```
$term = urldecode($this->request->query['term']);
```

That makes sense, because the jquery autocompate sends out the tag in the url.