# MySQL UTF-8 Collation not working as I would expect

Tags: mysql, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for case insensitive MySQL collation where “a” != “ä”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044268/looking-for-case-insensitive-mysql-collation-where-a-a)

I'm struggling with this `utf8` nonsense, I create a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

I insert a single row:

```
INSERT INTO `test`(`name`) VALUES ('Cryptïc');
```

I query against the table:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `test` WHERE `name` LIKE 'Cryptic';
```

I get result set:

```
+---------+
| name    |
+---------+
| Cryptïc |
+---------+
```

`i` should not equal `ï`, a little help?

Comment: or [I get dual results from mysql query when using international charachters, i.e Å/Ä=A & Ö=O,](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4018950)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `utf8_bin` instead of `utf8_general_ci`.

With `utf8_general_ci`, similar characters (like `i` and `ï`) are treated as the same character in comparisons and sorting. The comparison is also case insensitive (hence the `_ci`), which means that `i` and `I` are also treated the same.

Other collations, like `utf8_unicode_ci` do better sorting, but still 'fail' on comparisons.